# Rest call containing text '${' is not working as expected

Tags: rest, postman, soapui

I was sending data to server through post call and when my XML/JSON contains '$' and '{' together like '${', server rejects the request. But the same works with RestMan and PostMan.
Issue can be replicated by modifying any request body to have '${' together

```
Sample API :- https://reqres.in/api/users - Method- POST , headers---> Content-Type application/json;
Request Body 1: - {
"name": "morpheus",
"job": "leader"
}

Request Body 2:-
{
"name": "morpheus",
"job": "${leader"
}
```

For Request Body 1, user gets created but for Request Body 2 I'm getting the following response:

```
<title>Error</title>
Bad Request
```

## The same request body works well with postman and RestMan.

Edit :- The API url I specified is just a public API to test rest services. I can not share the actual code so I replicated the issue using public  test APIs and soapUi. If it's working fine through restman I'm not sure how it could be related to code. I tested many APIs with soapUi to verify it and issue seems to be with '${' only. I'm not sure but maybe soapUi internally uses it to detect expression or something else.
If it helps , I debugged my code and whenever I provide '${' through soapui, content-length value in header increases by 800-900 characters.

Comment: So the problem seems to be in your code and in the way you post your data. Unfortunatly you do not share this part of code, so that it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I made the edit and provided the necessary details. The URL I provided for API is for a public API to test REST services using restclients or to consume them directly in the application. And issue seems to appear only when '${' are together, that only in soapUi. Other rest clients are giving the response as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoapUI treats the characters `${...}` as [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/property-expansion.html).

In order to treat this literally, you will need to provide an extra dollar sign: `$${something`.

In the future, on the request pane, if you click on "Raw" you will see exactly what was sent.

Comment: Yes that's what I was guessing. Thanks for the confirmation. I tried the same in Endpoint Explorer in soapui and it was working fine. So I looked into the source code and discovered that project interface is based on JAVA swing and endpoint explorer was based on HTML and JQUERY.  So , as far as rest is considered, we can avoid the issue by using endpoint explorer.